# How to set order of new sharepoint list columns programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am having a Sharepoint list "Order" and it have 5 columns.

Now i am adding a new column in this List programmatically(C#),but i want to set the order of this column.How to do it programmatically?

```
    private void  CreateColumn(string splist)
    {
        using(SPSite site=new SPSite(SiteUrl))
        {
            using(SPWeb web=site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(splist);
                if (list != null)
                {
                    bool checkField = list.Fields.ContainsField("HiddenColumn");

                    if (!checkField)
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        list.Fields.Add("HiddenColumn", SPFieldType.Text, false);
                        list.Update();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code ? have you tried something that doesn't work? What version on Sharepoint ?

Comment: I am using Sharepoint 2010.